# Touch functions do not work properly in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch, universal

I am making an universal SpriteKit game. I test my game both iPhone and iPad. In iPhone everything works fine and also in simulator  but in iPad touch functions do not work properly on the Game Scene. For example; in game scene I have 4 sprites I can touch one of them but the others don't work in iPad. Have any ideas ? What is going on ?

```
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        for var i=1; i<ballNode.count; i++ {
            if nodeAtPoint(location) == ballNode[i].node && !ballNode[i].character.locked  {
                ballNode[i].touchingNode = true
                ballNode[i].angelLabel.hidden = false



                let seq = SKAction.sequence([fadeIn, fadeOut])
                ballNode[i].node.childNodeWithName("laserAni")!.hidden = false
                ballNode[i].node.childNodeWithName("laserAni")!.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(seq))

                if ballNode[i].node.name == BallTypes.multipleGuns {
                    ballNode[i].node.childNodeWithName("laserAni2")!.hidden = false
                    ballNode[i].node.childNodeWithName("laserAni2")!.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(seq))

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: What's the code that you are using to "touch" them?

Comment: In touch began function I use  if nodeAtPoint(location) == node {// code here }

Comment: Could you post the code? the code shouldn't fail to work just because you are using an IPad

Comment: Yes I cannot understand, code works perfect on İphone but not in iPad ? which part you want to see ?

Comment: Your `touches` method(s) or any other part that handles the touch events

Comment: I am looping an array elements to detect the touches. The array has 4 elements.

Comment: Which element in the array are you able to touch??

Comment: All of them. According the certain rule which is if the type is not locked.

Comment: I mean when you are on the iPad and on the IPhone what node are you able to touch (as in what indexes in the array can you access)

Comment: I can touch second in iPad. The others not work. In iPhone all works fine.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Can you post where you make the array and add the nodes in? I think that might be where the problem could be

Comment: I have 4 levels, adding array elements into the functions. For example, in level 1 all elements work fine but in level 3 I said before. If the problem is in the array then it should not work in iPhone. :) I am going to be crazy. I forget to say.  I cannot detect the UI buttons also back or main button do not work too.

Comment: O ok. If you change in the for loop `var i = 1` to `var i = 0` what happens? Are you able to touch only the first node now? Or the second one as well? Also, put `NSLog("%i",ballNode.count)` inside the for loop but outside the if statement. Then tell me what the output is each time

Comment: You probably cannot detect the UI buttons for another reason (because you have to do some configuration to get UI elements working with sprite-kit) I think the array is a separate problem

Comment: Nothing happens when I change the i but I figure out something when I change the position of ballNode[3] to the near of 2 ı can touch 3 as well. However, when change the ballNode[2] to near 3 I cannot touch anything. Very interesting things happen in my code :)

Comment: I use the buttons are also sprites. I test when I change the array elements position right side of the screen I can detect the touches. but on the left side not. I think this is a bug. I does not make any sense...

Comment: Did you create the sprites from images you loaded in?

Comment: Yes I use vector images in pdf format. My iPad iOS ver 8.3 game is supporting 8.0 or higher. In iPhone iOS ver 9.0 is relevant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think that there is some kind of bug here.

First of all, you start looping in the array at index 1, which is actually the second element in the array. Ballnode[0] is the first index. Unless you are keeping this index blank, then no device at all should be able to access the first element. Second of all, if you noticed that when you moved position of the sprites you could access them, then that means some of them overlapped. You should check your images and crop them or edit as necessary to make sure they fit without overlapping. iOS 9 is known to have many bugs and it seems like you might have discovered one. My advice here is to trust iOS 8 as your default testing OS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I delete the background image and works fine. I think zPositions sets wrong. I accept your answer

Comment: Yeah no problem, glad it was that simple of a fix!